# View as a function pointer

Tags: swiftui

Is it possible to declare a View as a var in some way, as in below struct?

```
struct OptionViews {
   var title: String
   var imageName: String
   var targetView: View
}
```

I want to use the above struct to present as an array of possible selections (as in a settings view) where if I click on an item a it should open the targetView. However, the above struct is not allowed due to "Protocol View can only be used as a generic constraint", is there a way around this or another way to accomplish this? I need to know which View should be opened when the specific item is selected, but if i cant specify the view as part of the item, that does not seem possible.

Thanks,
Marcus

Comment: You try to combine *view* and *model* (separated layers) into one, but that's wrong design concept, moreover even if it would be so (and it is possible technically) you will almost definitely have some troubles with update/refresh in final view hierarchy of something. Model should live in model, view should live in views and shown depending on model. MVVM, this is a native concept for SwiftUI.

Comment: Make each selection a `NavigationLink`, and give them different destinations.

Comment: @George, thanks I will explore using NavigationLink, it should be a workable solution I think, thanks!

Comment: @CaptainMJ Is this array of options dynamic, or static (will it change)?

Comment: Its largely static, its for listing the options in the Settings tab in my app (looks just like normal iPhone Settings style), I may have one Admin or Developer selection that should not be visible to all users, but I think that can still be considered static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what @Asperi said in comment is right. Not sure what you exactly want but maybe you could make your struct generic like:

```swift
struct OptionViews<Content> where Content: View {
   var title: String
   var imageName: String
   var targetView: Content
}

// example
let optionViews = OptionViews(title: "Titel",
                              imageName: "Image",
                              targetView: Image(systemName: "heart"))
```

Comment: I mean that the `Image` for example would only occur in the actual `View`, within a `NavigationLink` destination. You don't really want to store views in your model, as Asperi says.

Comment: Rico, that looks like a great suggestion, I will explore this as well. Many thanks for the help!

Comment: @CaptainMJ Just use a `NavigationLink`. There's not much more to it - you can have 3 for example in a `List`, each with a different destination. Storing the view in the model is unnecessarily complicated and could cause update issues.

Comment: George, I may not have been clear there but by 'imageName' I was referring to the system name of an image to be displayed to the selectable title. Which once selected launches the target view, for example ```Image(systemName: "person"; Text("My Profile")```. But i think the suggestions provided will guide me in the right direction.

Comment: @George maybe `NavigationLink` doesn't really fit good his problem; without a bigger context we can't really say what's better to do

Comment: @RicoCrescenzio I wouldn't store the `NavigationLink` in the struct, I mean that would just be in the view `body` or whatever (`ContentView` for example). If this array of options is dynamic, I guess it can make sense to store the view destination, if you can't just `switch` over the current option.

Comment: @George yes sorry, I got wrong at first read